# Not deleting child rows in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two Entity in my web app.One is UserDetails and another one is OrderDetails.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinTable(name="USER_CART",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CART_ID")
        )

private Collection<CartList> cartList= new ArrayList<CartList>();

public Collection<CartList> getCartList() {
    return cartList;
}
public void setCartList(Collection<CartList> cartList) {
    this.cartList = cartList;
}

}
```

And I am trying to delete the CartList from the UserDetails by following code.

```
List<CartList> cartLists=new ArrayList<>();

    try{

    Query<CartList> query=session.createQuery("from UserDetails where userEmail=?");
    query.setString(0, user);

    cartLists=query.list();

    System.out.print(String.valueOf(cartLists));

    for(CartList temp:cartLists){

        session.delete(temp);

    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return "unsuccessful";
    }
```

But following code is throwing the error.

```
   WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-6]     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ebdb`.`USER_CART`, CONSTRAINT `FKcdargk7kuorrqnumdp06jtqua` FOREIGN KEY (`CART_ID`) REFERENCES `CART_LIST` (`id`))
 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.release HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Please help me.I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete record from parent table(OrderDetails) whose records are associated with child table (UserDetails ) it means parent table column is used as foreign key(CART_ID) in your child table you have to first delete data from child table corresponding to records in parent table.
other salution is that during table creation you have to specify condition whether you want to delete all child record associated with parent record.
For example :

```
 CREATE TABLE PADRE{
IDPADRE INT PRIMARY KEY
IDABUELO INT CONSTRAINT FK_IDABUELO FOREIGN KEY IDABUELO REFERENCES ABUELO(IDABUELO) ON DELETE CASCADE
}
```

Comment: I  want to delete only rows from the child table.what will be the best way.I am not able to find anything on internet also.It becomes cumbersome for me.